# Regex for parsing complicated array

Tags: c#, arrays, regex

I'm trying parse input string which looks like 
`array[digit or expression or array, digit or expression or array]`
 So I need to get values in `[ , ]`. I was trying to get them using this regex:

```
(array1)\[(.*)\,(.*)\]
```

to get values of `(.*)` capturing groups, but it doen't work, because it's greedy quantifier, so in the case of:

```
array1[ array2[4,3] , array2[1,6] ]
```

I will get `array2[4,3] , array2[1,` as first capturing group and `6` as a second which is not right.

How can I get `array2[4,3]` as first and `array2[1,6]` as second capturing group? Or `array2[array3[1,1],3]` and `5+3` if the input string is `array1[ array2[array3[1,1],3] , 5+3 ]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of balancing groups:

```
array\d*\[\s*((?:[^\[\]]|(?<o>\[)|(?<-o>\]))+(?(o)(?!))),\s*((?:[^\[\]]|(?<o>\[)|(?<-o>\]))+(?(o)(?!)))\]
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/TXEZIx) on your last string.

A breakdown:

```
array\d*\[\s*    # Match array with its number (if any), first '[' and any spaces
(
  (?:                 
    [^\[\]]      # Match all non-brackets
  |
    (?<o>\[)     # Match '[', and capture into 'o' (stands for open)
  |
    (?<-o>\])    # Match ']', and delete the 'o' capture
  )+
  (?(o)(?!))     # Fails if 'o' doesn't exist
)
,\s*             # Match comma and any spaces
(                # Repeat what was above...
  (?:            
    [^\[\]]      # Match all non-brackets
  |
    (?<o>\[)     # Match '[', and capture into 'o' (stands for open)
  |
    (?<-o>\])    # Match ']', and delete the 'o' capture
  )+
  (?(o)(?!))     # Fails if 'o' doesn't exist
)
\]               # Last closing brace
```

Comment: This fails if you add a third array.

Comment: @rbrundritt There's only one array with (at most) 2 sub arrays (but which can have more sub arrays) in the question. I'm not sure what you mean...?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to allow it to work with any number of sub arrays.

Comment: @rbrundritt Then the capture groups wouldn't be needed. OP would have to make only one capture group containing all the sub arrays separated by comma in this condition.