# How do I extract text that lies between brackets in special order?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have following string:

```
Find string inside brackets [C#.net [C# Only] [PHP and SQl [MySQL] ] ] and [Vb.net] examples.
```

and I want to output the following:

```
   1 -  [C#.net [C# Only] [PHP and SQl [MySQL] ] ]
   2 -  [C# Only]
   3 -  [PHP and SQl [MySQL] ]
   4 -  [MySQL]
   5 -  [Vb.net]
```

My Code is:

```
string regularExpressionPattern = @"\[([^]]*)\]";
string text = "Find string inside brackets [C#.net [C# Only] [PHP and SQl [MySQL] ] ] and [Vb.net] examples.";
Regex re = new Regex(regularExpressionPattern);
int i = 0 ;
foreach (Match m in re.Matches(text))
{
    i++;
    Console.WriteLine(i + " -  " + m.Value);
}
```

And current (incorrect) output:

```
1 -  [C#.net [C# Only]
2 -  [PHP and SQl [MySQL]
3 -  [Vb.net]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need balancing groups. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22758842/1578604) is not an exact duplicate but the regex there can be used to solve your problem. First the basic regex:

```
\[(?:[^\[\]]|(?<o>\[)|(?<-o>\]))+(?(o)(?!))\]
```

---

```
\[            # Match an opening square bracket
(?:           # Group begin
  [^\[\]]     # Match non-square brackets
|             # Or
  (?<o>\[)    # An opening square bracket which we name 'o'.
|             # Or 
  (?<-o>\])   # A closing square bracket and we remove an earlier square bracket
)+            # Repeat the group as many times as possible
(?(o)(?!))    # Fail if a group named 'o' exists at this point
\]            # Match the final closing square bracket
```

---

Then to get the inner matches, you can use a lookahead and a capture group so you can get overlapping matches:

```
(?=(\[(?:[^\[\]]|(?<o>\[)|(?<-o>\]))+(?(o)(?!))\]))
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/2ocYdi)

Comment: I forgot to mention: use `m.Groups[1].Value` later in your code since the above regex gets the result in the first capture group. You can see I used exactly that in the demo

Comment: I am very week in regex where i  can find good tutorial our example for learn

Comment: @Milad You could perhaps use http://www.regular-expressions.info/ I personally look there, or search on StackOverflow because chances are either a similar question has been asked before, or a slightly different problem has been solved and I can use the solution after adapting it to what I need :)

Answer (score 3):

I know that regular expressions are wonderful and people use them to do all sort of wonderful things. But the simple truth is that they are a pain. While I'm sure that they have many wonderful users it is not from nothing that Jamie Zawinski "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems." quote remains oft quoted.

And it isn't that you need to be beaten with staves for using regex but perhaps just demonstrating that there infinite other ways? So I adapted a common one, it isn't perfect; it doesn't enforce paring of brackets, it will get monster messed up if more brackets close than open, and it is missing some braces that would make it more readable but:

```
static class StringExtensions
{
    private static char open = '[';
    private static char close = ']';
    public static string[] Brackets(this string str)
    {
        //Set up vars
        StringBuilder[] builders = new StringBuilder[str.Count(x => x == open)];
        for (int h = 0; h < builders.Count(); h++)
            builders[h] = new StringBuilder();
        string[] results = new string[builders.Count()];
        bool[] tracker = new bool[builders.Count()];
        int haveOpen = 0;
        //loop up string
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            //if opening bracket
            if (str[i] == open)
                tracker[haveOpen++] = true;
            //loop over tracker
            for (int j = 0; j < tracker.Length; j++)
                if (tracker[j])
                    //if in this bracket append to the string
                    builders[j].Append(str[i]);
            //if closing bracket
            if (str[i] == close)
                tracker[Array.FindLastIndex<bool>(tracker, p => p == true)] = false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < builders.Length; i++)
            results[i] = builders[i].ToString();
        return results;
    }
}
```

And you then get to use it like

```
foreach (string part in text.Brackets())
{
    Console.WriteLine(part);
}
```